# Polymer CSS variables not being replaced

Tags: css, polymer, css-variables

I've inherited a web app built using Polymer for the front-end. When I run the various Docker commands, it *mostly* works, but there are some CSS issues. Specifically, some of the Polymer styles don't seem to be compiled. For example, with the `<paper-dialog>` element, the color variables aren't being replaced:

```
.paper-dialog-0 {
  display: block;
  margin: 24px 40px;

  background: --primary-background-color;
  color: --primary-text-color;;;;
}

// ...

.paper-dialog-0  .buttons {
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 24px;
  margin: 0;
  color: --primary-color;;;
}
```

In another example, a bunch of the icons are all placed atop one another and not being positioned properly.

I've run the various Gulp commands that came with the project, which includes vulcanizing everything. For the most part, the styles do seem to be "polymery". I have never used Polymer before, so I'm a little lost on how to actually build the components into HTML and CSS. Is there an obvious step I've missed that wasn't documented in the project?

Answer (score 2):

[CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) (a.k.a. variables) are a web technology not specific to Polymer and are supported by most browsers, so it's likely they're not meant to be compiled or replaced in your project.

As to your code, there's one problem: To use a custom property, you must use the `var()` CSS function:

```
.paper-dialog-0 {
  display: block;
  margin: 24px 40px;

  background: var(--primary-background-color);
  color: var(--primary-text-color);
}
```

Comment: I think this is coming directly from a paper polymer element -- we haven't touched any of the code in that element. What should its styles compile to normally? Does the compiled polymer stylesheet include css variables? I'm reluctant to change the output css since (i assume) it'll just get overwritten with the next vulcanization.

Comment: I don't know what your built process looks like, but like I said CSS custom properties are supported by most browsers and so I wouldn't expect them to be compiled or replaced. The browser understands them or, for older browsers, they are handled by a polyfill such as ShadyCSS.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're expecting the build output to contain literal values instead of CSS variables, but [CSS variables do not require this string replacement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables). The browser automatically uses the value specified by the CSS variable (with the help of polyfills).

Regarding how to build the components, that could vary widely, but most Polymer projects use the [`polymer-cli`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli) to build (for minification, bundling, etc.). It's also possible to have your own Gulp script that employs parts of `polymer-cli` for maximum customization of the build (see [custom-build template](https://github.com/PolymerElements/generator-polymer-init-custom-build)).